# css - absolute position from top, horizontally centered div

Tags: css, css-position, centering

I've looked at a googol google results without finding any that work.

I need to have my div (height 333 px, width 550 px) to be centered horizontally and always be 275 px from the top.  Every time I try to do this it just disappears.

Comment: Please share the markup you are using to try to accomplish this. It will help us determine what is going on.

Comment: You could use the singleton pattern. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312806/php-static-class-initializer

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If the div should sit on top you have to use `position:absolute`. Otherwise, the answer from @sdleihssirhc should work.

### Example with positioning

```
#middlebox
{
    position:    absolute;
    top:         275px;
    left:        50%;    /* move the left edge to the center … */
    margin-left: -275px; /* … and move it to the left half the box’ width. */
    z-index:     9999;   /* Try to get it on top. */
}
```

Use tools like [Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/) or [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) to inspect the properties if it still disappears.

Comment: yeah, this works perfectly.  thanks!  slight typo, if the box is 550px wide the margin left should be -225, not -275.

Comment: @captainandcoke 550 / 2 = 275. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the content and context, you could just set that div's margin:

```
margin: 275px auto 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're thinking of static positioning, I don't think that you would need to use absolute positioning at all. Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:550px; height:333px; background-color:orange; margin: 275px auto">
Is this what you want?
</div>
</body>
</html>
```