# initiliazing static variables with composer

Tags: php, composer-php

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/3313137/569976 ircmaxell says the following:

> I use a public static method **init**() on my static classes that require initialization (or at least need to execute some code). Then, in my autoloader, when it loads a class it checks is_callable($class, '**init**'). If it is, it calls that method. Quick, simple and effective...

That post, however, is from 2010 and a lot has changed since then. My question is...  does Composer support anything like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer's autoloader isn't going to automatically call init methods for you, but that doesn't stop you from using your own autoloader instead.

---

https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

> **Note:** Composer provides its own autoloader. If you don't want to use that one, you can just include `vendor/composer/autoload_*.php` files, which return associative arrays allowing you to configure your own autoloader.